How to decrypt old files that were encrypted using ES File explorer
I have old files that I encrypted using ES File explorer a few years back that I would like to decrypt. I know the password but ES File Explorer is no longer available on the app store. Is there another tool or work around that will enable me to decrypt these files?
Thank you.

The workaround portion is on-topic here.  Software recommendations, however, are on-topic only at Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

The APK (app/installation file) of ES File Explorer can be downloaded from APK Mirror. However, I don't know which version may work to decrypt your files, you might have to do a trial & error for this. Make sure to create a backup before testing on a few files first.
